# How can custom collectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm new in Swift. I want to create a simple filling word app using UICollectionView. How can i custom UICollectionViewCell when the answer has 2 words like "Hello World". I want "World" will enter in the next row. And please show me how can center the cell that means "Hello" and "World" are center? Thank for your helping. Here is my code:

```
    var arrayCharacter = ["H","E","L","L","O","W","O","R","L","D"]
    extension QuestionVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arrayCharacter.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "quizColCell", for: indexPath) as! QuizCollectionCell
            cell.lblCharacter.text = arrayCharacter[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to write your own collection view layout, and put hello and world in different sections, probably.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: @TrungNguyen no one is probably gonna just do the work for you. But you should google and learn to create UICollection View sections, then post your work and you will probably get some better feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways I can think of :
**first way** - consider to redesign the DATA from :
var arrayCharacter = ["H","E","L","L","O","W","O","R","L","D"].
to
var arrayWords = [ "HELLO", "WORLD"]

Each collectionViewCell will represent one WORD.
Each cell will be 1 row (full width) 
In that cell you will create label for each letter (and hide labels you don't use for the word)

**The second way**, by using SECTIONS (google collectionView sections).
the DATA need to be :
array of array :
sections[0] = ["h","e", "l","l","o"].
sections[1] = ["w","o","r","l","d"]